# Interprocedural (multi-file) AST generation with clang

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a huge C project and I want to create AST for a particular C file in that project with clang. I also need to find function definitions when an external function is called (so like when I see `foo()` I could find where `foo` was defined, not declared). I couldn't find any information on how I can link my project when I'm parsing with clang to get the AST so that clang can find function definitions. Any ideas?

Comment: gtags can find definition. Set GTAGSLIBPATH appropriately.